# Is there a way to show a <tr> only if there are no other visible rows in the <tbody> using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm aware of the ability to show and hide with jQuery; unfortunately, it would be unmanageable to pass around all the necessary parameters, so what I'm looking for is a CSS trick that will make the row invisible unless all the other rows are hidden.

I tried using a `style="margin-bottom: -20px"`, but this had no effect. Is there something like this that would work?

Comment: "No other rows" or "no other _visible_ rows"?

Comment: Can you show your current HTML/CSS? How are the rows hidden? With a class? `style="display: none"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show an element iff it's the only child of its parent like this:

```
tbody > tr.Special {
    display: none;
}

tbody > tr.Special:only-child {
    display: table-row;
}
```

This [will not work on IE<9](http://www.caniuse.com/#)

Comment: `:first-child:last-child` can be simplified to `:only-child` (unless specificity is an issue). I gather the same browsers that support `:last-child` will support `:only-child` as well.

Comment: This will still hide the row if there are other hidden children; is there a way to combine it with visibility?